# implement matlabs graycomatrix() in vc++ with openCv

Tags: .net, opencv

how to implement  matlabs graycomatrix() in vc++ with openCv;
is there same of graycomatrix() in openCV?

Comment: It would help if you explain what `graycomatrix()` does so that the non-matlab-but-opencv community can help you. And which particular functionality you want to emulate.

Answer (score 0):

Co-ocurrence is not implemented in OpenCV.

I strongly encourage you to write one (maybe based on Octave implementation -  to be free, open source) and submit it to OpenCV :)